# Creating different MarkerFilters according to a certain condition in Logback.xml

Tags: java, log4j, logback, slf4j

Recently I've been working with logback and everything was going smooth until I tried to use Marker Filters together with the conditional xml tags.

What I wanted to do is to have a marker filtering system that would, depending on a property previously set, choose the adequate marker filters for my appenders.

My current code is bellow:

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
    <if condition='property("severityLevel").equals("SEVERITY-2")'>
        <then>
            <turboFilter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.MarkerFilter">
                <Marker>SEVERITY-1</Marker>
                <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
           </turboFilter>
        </then>
    </if>

    <!-- Console Appender -->
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level - ${appName} - %marker - %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
     </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

The property severityLevel comes from the configurator property that I set before initializing the logger:

```
LoggerContext aLoggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
JoranConfigurator aConfigurator = new JoranConfigurator();
aConfigurator.setContext(aLoggerContext);
aLoggerContext.reset();

aLoggerContext.putProperty(APPLICATION_NAME, config.getApplicationName());
aLoggerContext.putProperty(LOG_MAX_FILE_SIZE, config.getLogMaxFileSize().toString());
aLoggerContext.putProperty(LOG_KEEP_FOR_DAYS, config.getLogKeepForDays().toString());
aLoggerContext.putProperty("severityLevel", "SEVERITY-2");

System.out.println(aLoggerContext.getProperty("severityLevel"));

try
{
  aConfigurator.doConfigure(FileUtils.cleanPath(FileUtils.determineServletRealPath(""), false) + LOGBACK_CONFIGURATION_FILE_PATH);
}
catch (JoranException e)
{
  StatusPrinter.printIfErrorsOccured(aLoggerContext);
  throw e;
}
```

The expected behaviour would be that only SEVERITY-2 level messages would be logged. Instead, I keep getting all messages.

If I take the If condition out of the logback.xml file it will work fine but I still need to have another condition for a SEVERITY-3 in which both level 2 and level 1 will be denied and therefore I would need the If condition.

Some status messages from the logs:

```
 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [vfs:/Applications/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/mw-file-extractor.war/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@6b14b260 - URL [vfs:/Applications/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/mw-file-extractor.war/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml] is not of type file
 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Will scan for changes in [vfs:/Applications/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/mw-file-extractor.war/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml] 
 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Setting ReconfigureOnChangeTask scanning period to 30 seconds
 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.conditional.IfAction - Could not find Janino library on the class path. Skipping conditional processing.
 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.conditional.IfAction - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#ifJanino
 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@726fa157 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

**Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: please add status messages generated internally by logback.

Comment: @Ceki Edited my question with the messaged generated by logback. First of all I would like to thank for the availability and awesome product you guys developed. I think I managed to read the log line I could not read at first. I'm missing that Janino library on the classpath as that should solve the issue. I will get back as soon as I try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out, with the help of @Ceki and Logback debug messages that I was missing the Janino library for the use of conditionals.

Adding both janino-3.0.8.jar and commons-compiler-3.0.8.jar fixed the issue.